# Raise Exception issue in big query scripting

Tags: exception, stored-procedures, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I would like to print the custom message as an exception error with the RAISE keyword in big query script.
But, the below command lines is throwing an error at the raise command. But, if I remove the raise command it is working fine.
Could you please help me how I have to raise a custom error message??
Also, to know more about the `RAISE [USING MESSAGE = message];`.

```
BEGIN
SELECT 1/0; -- attempts to divide by zero
RAISE USING message = "divisible with zero is not allowed.";
EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN
SELECT FORMAT("Hey, you. When you executed %s at %s, it caused an error: %s. Please don't do that.", @@error.statement_text, @@error.formatted_stack_trace, @@error.message);
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The RAISE statement must only be used within an EXCEPTION clause. The RAISE statement will re-raise the exception that was caught, and preserve the original stack trace.

Ref: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#raise

So if you want to raise an exception with custom message, it should be:

```
BEGIN
SELECT 1/0; -- attempts to divide by zero
EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN
RAISE USING message = FORMAT("Hey, you. When you executed %s at %s, it caused an error: %s. Please don't do that.", @@error.statement_text, @@error.formatted_stack_trace, @@error.message);
END;
```